# FB Login, jquery not working on chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, facebook-login

My code looks as below

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   $.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_UK/all.js', function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
        channelUrl: '//localhost/channel.html',
        status: true, // check login status
        cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
            // app, and response.authResponse supplies
            // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
            // request, and the time the access token
            // and signed request each expire
            Dosomethinguseful();
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            // the user is logged in to Facebook,
            // but has not authenticated your app
        } else {
            // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
            FB.login(function (response) {
                if (response.session) {
                    dosomething();
                }
            });
        }
    });
   });
});
```

Above code works great on safari and firefox. However, on chrome i dont see anything happening. Debugging shows no error.

Need help.

is there a working example of calling FB auth using jquery?

===========

tried the code from http://geekswithblogs.net/ptahiliani/archive/2013/08/23/facebook-login-authentication-example.aspx. It also doesnt work on chrome :(. I get following error

```
'Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.facebook.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://s-static.ak.facebook.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "https". Protocols must match.'
```

Comment: _“Debugging shows no error”_ – so what debugging measures did you try? And did you try embedding the SDK the way the docs recommend, instead of the getScript mumbo-jumbo?

Comment: jquery has to be done this way or if i udnerstand that correctly : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/howto/jquery/

Comment: Ah, didn’t know FB recommended doing thing this way in combination with jQuery. Well, that leaves the first part of the question.

Comment: I also tried plain javascript mode. I am getting this error  Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.facebook.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://s-static.ak.facebook.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "https". Protocols must match.
 I am testing my app on localhost with no ssl certificate

Comment: That’s a common error in Chrome, has something to do with the cross-domain communication stuff the SDK tries to do in the background – but that should not affect functionality. Try logging the responses you get to console. And also, FB.login should not be called automatically, because that means a high risk of the popup blocker just catching the login popup. General advice is to only call this method on explicit user interaction, f.e. click on a link/button.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an old question but this happened to me recently.

We found when using a self signed certificate we would get a grey "broken" screen in facebook. However, when visiting the site directly (ie not via facebook) and we accept this illegit certificate THEN visited the facebook app it worked fine.

Seems Chrome won't ask you to continue if it detects an invalid cert when pulling in page resources via HTTPS. But it remembers if you accept one if requesting directly via HTTPS.

Good luck :)